# Isn't django now() supposed to be in the default time zone?

Tags: django

This might be a bit of a trivial question, but can't I get django now() to be in the time zone defined in `settings.TIME_ZONE`?

This is what is actually happening:

```
>>> from django.utils import timezone
>>> timezone.now()
datetime.datetime(2012, 5, 30, 16, 30, 0, 782087, tzinfo=<UTC>)
>>> timezone.get_default_timezone()
<DstTzInfo 'Asia/Singapore' SMT+6:55:00 STD>
```

Comment: I bet `timezone.get_current_timezone()` is also 'Asia/Singapore'. Just to make the picture complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or I could just read the source:

```
def now():
    """
    Returns an aware or naive datetime.datetime, depending on settings.USE_TZ.
    """
    if settings.USE_TZ:
        # timeit shows that datetime.now(tz=utc) is 24% slower
        return datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=utc)
    else:
        return datetime.now()
```

Answer is nope, I have to adjust it myself.

Answer (score 13):

Django's [source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/utils/timezone.py#L235-L239) (as displayed in the chosen answer) explains the concept of `timezone.now()`:

1. `datetime.now()` yields the current time (in your active timezone!) without timezone information ("naive datetime"), whereas ...
2. `timezone.now()` *always* yields the **current time in UTC** (!) *with* timezone information.

This is irritating at first sight, yes. They could have decided to yield the current time of the active timezone, but they didn't. You can still use `timezone.localtime(timezone.now())` to get what you want:

```py
from django.utils import timezone
from datetime import datetime

timezone.get_current_timezone()
# <DstTzInfo 'Antarctica/McMurdo' LMT+11:39:00 STD>
datetime.now()
# datetime.datetime(2014, 8, 19, 20, 8, 8, 440959)
timezone.localtime(timezone.now())
# datetime.datetime(2014, 8, 19, 20, 8, 14, 889429, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Antarctica/McMurdo' NZST+12:00:00 STD>)
timezone.now()
# datetime.datetime(2014, 8, 19, 8, 8, 22, 273529, tzinfo=<UTC>)
datetime.utcnow()
# datetime.datetime(2014, 8, 19, 8, 8, 29, 769312)
```

For newcomers and ordinary users `timezone.localtime(timezone.now())` is probably the most intuitive. A local time which still retains timezone information.

**EDIT:** The standard library equivalent for a timezone-aware local time is `datetime.now().astimezone()`. [astimezone](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.astimezone) applies the system local timezone by default, which allows you to correctly convert any timezone-aware datetime to your local time. To set an arbitrary timezone using timezone names you need the [pytz](https://pypi.org/project/pytz/) package.

```py
from datetime import datetime, timezone
import pytz

datetime.now()
# datetime.datetime(2022, 9, 14, 5, 26, 35, 146551)
datetime.now().astimezone()
# datetime.datetime(2022, 9, 14, 5, 26, 44, 19645, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(seconds=7200), 'CEST'))
datetime.now(tz=timezone.utc)
# datetime.datetime(2022, 9, 14, 3, 26, 51, 203917, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
datetime.now(tz=timezone.utc).astimezone()
# datetime.datetime(2022, 9, 14, 5, 26, 58, 546724, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(seconds=7200), 'CEST'))
datetime.now(tz=pytz.timezone('Europe/Kiev'))
# datetime.datetime(2022, 9, 14, 6, 27, 38, 714633, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Kiev' EEST+3:00:00 DST>)
```

Comment: Some more examples of using `datetime` (plus interesting background information and historic facts) are available from the Miroslav Šedivý's talk on "[A Day Has Only 24±1 Hours](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=icVMirr1Kis&t=1h7m30s)" (video starting at 1:07:30) from [EuroPython 2019](https://ep2019.europython.eu/talks/nqZBcMf-a-day-has-only-241-hours/).

Answer (score 0):

It depends

> now()
>   Returns an aware or naive datetime that represents the current point in time when USE_TZ is True or False respectively.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django-utils-timezone

So all would indicate that USE_TZ is false in your case, and it's not taking the TZ in consideration.

Comment: They just mean timezone aware vs. not time zone aware dates. The wording seemed to imply they would be in the *right* time zone, but apparently not.

Comment: Yes, I came to that conclusion by reading the doc in light of your example. I probably would have expected it to use the default TZ anyway.

Comment: This (usually) has nothing to do with `USE_TZ`. `timezone.now()` *always* returns UTC time. If you want local time you need to convert the *presentation* using `timezone.localtime()`. Note that the time will stay the same of your `datetime` object, time presentation *and* timezone will change simultaneously. Try a comparison: ```t = timezone.now() ; t == timezone.localtime(t)```